# Injecting mocks into Browserify for testing

Tags: unit-testing, browserify

I know, Browserify isn't really a DI framework, but is it possible to "inject", or somehow fake injecting, mock data into an application during unit testing?

For example, to test the function:

```
var MyModel = require('./models/My.js');

function doSomething() {
  // do something with model.
}
```

with a mock My.js, like

```
describe('Do Something', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    // replace './models/My.js' with a Mock implementation.
  });

  it('with model', function() {
    // ... test
  });
})
```

what goes in the `beforeEach` function?

Comment: Did you find any of the options from dannyfritz useful? Personally I feel rewireify would fit my needs the most.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few tools for mocking `require` calls in browserify.

- https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquireify
- https://github.com/i-like-robots/rewireify
- https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-swap
- https://github.com/Colingo/mock
- https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery

I haven't personally used these. Also, mockery wasn't written with Browserify in mind so mockery might not even work. The others were written for Browserify though so they should work with little effort. :) Proxyquireify and Rewireify seem to be the only 2 active within the last year though.

Comment: @nicholas: add feedback on these ?

Comment: I prefer Rewireify personnally, since everything that can be done with proxyquireify can be done directly with Jasmine `spyOn`

Comment: Interesting @FelixD. you may have insight to shed some light on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516371/browserify-rewireify-unit-testing-how-to-inject-dependencies-without-a-bundle ?