# Browserify/Rewireify unit testing, how to inject dependencies without a bundle?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, bundle, mocha.js, browserify

Browserify handles dependencies nicely by requiring them and creating a bundle where all is in order. When unit testing a module that has it's own dependencies it's somewhat more complicated though.

My tests are using `mocha`, `sinon`, `chai`.

My app is built on `backbone`, `marionette`, and some `jQuery` plugins.

I'm putting it together with `grunt` and `browserify`, all is written in coffeescript.

For instance, I have a module looking like this:

```
# Global, because swosh won't know what jQuery is otherwise.
$ = global.jQuery = require 'jquery'
require '../jqueryPlugins/swosh.js'

module.exports =
  App.MyView: Mn.ItemView.extend
    # Here I make use of jQuery plugin swosh
```

When I'm testing this piece of code, I'll do it like this:

```
App = require '../src/swoshViews.coffee'

theView = new App.MyView
describe 'Swooshing'
  it 'swooshes', ->
    # I create a spy/stub of the jQuery plugin
    # and make sure it's called as expected.
```

Since Browserify isn't a dependency injection framework, the jQuery plugin will not be available for the module, there are some options to make that happen. The most suitable for me seems to be [Rewireify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewireify).

I'm running my tasks with Grunt, where browserify is run win the transformations `['coffeeify', 'rewireify']`. However, and here's my question:

My unit tests, being run with `npm test`, doesn't use a browser.

`package.json` extract:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha"
},
```

Grunt>Browserify will arrange a .js bundle for me with `rewireify` baked in, though how do I apply this for my npm test task? My npm test script simply runs `mocha`, as seen above, which will run tests in all my unit test files, no need for a bundle. How do I make use of `rewireify` this way?